# If (condition1 && condition2 && condition3 && condition4 == condition1) ? Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, parameters

I'm making a card game for the iPad (Panic, Nervous Breakdown,Stress). To win you need to have a full set of 4 matching cards, I'm trying to get an IF statement that will work to make sure that all of the 4 cards are equal. Here is my current code:

```
if ([cards objectAtIndex:4] && [cards objectAtIndex:5] && [cards objectAtIndex:6] && [cards objectAtIndex:7] == [cards objectAtIndex:5]) {
        //Deck one is good!
        NSLog(@"P1D1, all clear");
}
```

Cards is a NSMuatableArray. If I have a 2x2 array with the data 4:3:2:1

I would only need to matching cards in slot 4 and 2 for the above statement to return true.

Comment: I gather that you're a complete novice at C.  Using `&&` does not mean to repeat the `==` test with the listed values.  Read up on the meaning of `&&`.

Comment: You also need to understand that an NS(Mutable)Array stores objects, not numbers.

Comment: You also don't want to compare the cards using `==`, but some kind of "equals" method.

Comment: @HotLicks I gather that you didn't read the question properly, this is Objecitve C not C. :P

Comment: @TheDeveloper - This is irrelevant, C and Objective-C share the same syntax for doing if/else statements using logical operators.

Comment: You should not even attempt Objective-C until you have a good understanding of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if([[cards objectAtIndex:4] isEqual:[cards objectAtIndex:5]] && [[cards objectAtIndex:6] isEqual:[cards objectAtIndex:5]] && [[cards objectAtIndex:7] isEqual:[cards objectAtIndex:5]]){
  //Deck one is good!
  NSLog(@"P1D1, all clear");
}
```

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
NSSet *distinctCardSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[cards subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 4)]];
if (distinctCardSet.count == 1)
{
    //Deck one is good!
    NSLog(@"P1D1, all clear");
}
```